# jQuery document ready will not work no matter how I write it

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps, document-ready

I feel like this should be a simple thing to fix, but I just can't get it to work. I am running a jQuery store locator script with google maps. The script requires two javascript files, jquery, and the google maps api. Finally, it calls the actual function to run the locator. The files are as follows:

```
jlocator.min.js
jplist.min.js
jlocator.activate.js (this is where is put the document.ready script)
jquery
google api script
```

I have the locator working perfectly fine in a non-wordpress test site. But in Wordpress, the store locator script simply won't run. This is in my functions.php page

```
function my_map_scripts() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'template-project-map.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'jplist-custom-script',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jplist.min.js',
            array( 'jquery' )
        );
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'jlocator-custom-script',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jlocator.min.js',
            array( 'jquery' )
        );
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'jlocator-activate-script',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jlocator.activate.js',
            array( 'jquery' )
        );
        wp_enqueue_script(
                'google-maps',
                'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js'
            );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_map_scripts' );
```

I've enqueued the .js files, and they are loading fine. I put alerts in each file just to double-check. I also used wp_script_is, at one point, to make sure jQuery was running.

The problem seems to be in my document ready code. I am using the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#jlocator').jlocator();
});
```

This is doing nothing. I even tried putting an alert in to see if that would work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#jlocator').jlocator();
    alert("activated");
});
```

Again, nothing. But if I remove this line:

```
jQuery('#jlocator').jlocator();
```

So that the codes reads:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        alert("activated");
    });
```

The alert fires fine. I also tried doing something like the code below just to see if it would work, but it didn't work, either. (.panel is a div on my page).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.panel').hide();
});
```

The above code worked fine in my non-Wordpress test site, though. It seems that anytime I use the following code to do something, it shuts everything else down.

```
jQuery('sometext')....
```

Is there something simple that I am missing here?

Also, I have tried writing the document ready as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#jlocator').jlocator();
    alert("activated");
});
```

and

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#jlocator').jlocator();
    alert("activated");
});
```

but still nothing works. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Error in console? Sounds like `jlocator()` method is undefined

Comment: I checked the error console, and I'm seeing several errors in regards to Google Maps API being on the page multiple times. I thought it might be from other maps plugins, but they are all deactivated. And I know I have only called the Google Maps API one time.

Also, even when I remove the call to jlocator(), if I replace it with something like jQuery('.panel').hide(), that doesn't work, either. Nothing works when I use jQuery at the start of the line.

Comment: You have to fix errors prior to expect your code to work. That's said, if `jQuery('.panel').hide();` doesn't work, maybe there is no element with this class at time you call it. Maybe `jQuery` is overwritten in some way(?!). Maybe, etc... Without seeing a minimalistic sample which replicates your issue, it is quite impossible to help you more.

Comment: I just used a fresh install of Wordpress to try this again. This time `jQuery('.panel').hide()` does work, but I'm still not seeing the map. In the error console, I am getting the following: TypeError: jQuery(...) is not a function. This error shows up twice (it's in each of my javascript files). It's referring to a line like this `jQuery(function(k){var..........` Do I have to alter my javascript files in any way (similar to the way the $ has to change to jQuery? I'm not sure where to begin with showing a minimal sample of the code. The only part giving me a problem is the call to locator()

Comment: Here is a link to the photo of the error console [link](http://i.imgur.com/ucScDgg.png)

Comment: You have to include jQuery before these plugins

Comment: @A.Wolff jQuery is added as a dependency so it will be included when enqueueing the scripts.

Comment: That's what I was hoping it was doing, but I still can't get it to work. And I've checked to make sure jQuery actually is running. It feels like the problem has to do with the jplist.min.js and jlocator.min.js files. And those are the files that are throwing the errors. I don't have to convert every $ to jQuery in those files, too, do I?

Comment: Ya the problem is related to these plugins (jplidt, jlocator). No this hasnothing to do with $ alias BUT because you are including jQuery AFTER these both plugins which are using jQuery. Im not a wordpress user but looks like you just need to include jQuery BEFORE them

Comment: @A. Wolff it appears that you were correct. For some reason, jQuery wasn't loading, even though I had a dependency set in my function before calling my js files. I'm not sure why that was happening. But I added the following code to my functions.php page, and it started working:


`// Load jQuery
  if ( !is_admin() ) {
     wp_deregister_script('jquery');
     wp_register_script('jquery', ("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"), false);
     wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  }`


I will mark that answer as correct. Thanks.

Comment: actually, how do I even mark the question as answered?

Comment: @jasonTakesManhattan Glad you've fixed it. To mark question, this need at least one answer. So you should answer it using your previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is now solved. For some reason, jQuery wasn't loading, even though I had a dependency set in my function before calling my js files. I'm not sure why that was happening. But I added the following code to my functions.php page, and it started working: `// Load jQuery if ( !is_admin() ) { wp_deregister_script('jquery'); wp_register_script('jquery', ("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"), false); wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); }`